# miktex 2.7 on win 7 problem: metafont modes not seen by initexmf, Yap

Tags: metafont

I am using MikTeX 2.7 + WinEdt 5.x on WinXP for many years without problems.

But after I installed it on another machine running Win 7, MikTeX appears to work 
partially: it compiles all LaTeX documents, produces ps and pdf outputs, generates 
necessary pk fonts but does not preview documents by Yap. Yap reports an error: 
"METAFONT: unknown ljfour mode".
What could be the reason of this problem within Windows 7 ?

Regards